# Multivariate convex optimization problem involving logarithms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Question-1:
$$\min_{a, b} \sum_{i=1}^K b_i f(\frac{a_i}{b_i}) $$

s.t.
$$ f(x) = (1+x) \log(1+x) -\log(x) - (1+x) \log(2)$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^K a_i = 1.$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^K b_i = 1.$$

$$  a,b > 0. $$

**My attempt so far**: $f(x)$ is convex. I wrote the Lagrangian, but could not solve for $x$. Also, $\nabla_x f(x)$ is zero at $x=1$. Then minimum for f(x) is at $x=1$. I am not sure if this helps.

Question-2: Thanks a lot to David M. for the answer to the Question-1. Now, I like to extend the question a little more to include solutions with $a_i=0$ or $b_i=0$.

$$\min_{a, b} \sum_{i=1}^K b_i I(a_i>0, b_i>0)f(\frac{a_i}{b_i}) $$

s.t.
$$ f(x) = (1+x) \log(1+x) -\log(x) - (1+x) \log(2)$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^K a_i = 1.$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^K b_i = 1.$$

$$  a,b\geq 0. $$

Comment: $\nabla_{x_i} f(x_i) =  1 + \log(1+x_i) - \frac{1}{x_i} - \log(2) $ and
$\nabla_{x_i} \nabla_{x_i} f(x_i) =  \frac{1}{1+x_i} + \frac{1}{x_i^2} > 0$  for $x_i > 0$ hence sum of convex functions is also convex.

Comment: The answer to the question you originally posed is $x_i=1/K$ for all $i$. Saw the new edit as I was about to submit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Sorry, I have stated the question wrong. But, can you describe the rough idea maybe I can use in the new one?

Comment: My argument still holds for the new edit.

Comment: I see. But solutions like $a_1=b_1=1$  and  $a_k=b_k=0$ for $k>1$ can also be added to the solution space?

Comment: Ah I was assuming $a,b\geq0$. If that’s not the case the problem is not convex.

Comment: $a,b\geq 0$ actually holds but unlike the first question this time they can be zero. Sorry, I forgot to add $a,b\geq 0$.

Comment: Depends how you deal with edge cases $1/\infty$, $0/0$ _etc._ but there’s no sensible way to define these cases which change what the minimum is.

Comment: I see. I add an indicator function to avoid such cases. So, if $a_i=0$ or $b_i=0$  then objective becomes zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objective function is a separable perspective function (see slide 20 of [these lecture notes](http://stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/functions.pdf)). Basically, because $f(\cdot)$ is convex, the function $g(a,b)=b\cdot f(a/b)$ is convex in $(a,b)$. Hence, your objective is convex as a sum of convex functions. Because both the equality constraints are affine, the KKT conditions are sufficient for this problem, since the Slater Condition is satisfied by the point $a_i=b_i=1/K$ for all $i=1,\dots,K$. In fact, we will show that this point is optimal.

The partial derivative of the objective function with respect to $a_i$ is
$$
f'\big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\big),
$$
and the partial derivative of the objective function with respect to $b_i$ is
$$
f\big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\big)-\frac{a_i}{b_i}\cdot f'\big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\big)
$$
If we let $\lambda$ and $\pi$ denote the dual multipliers for the constraints $\sum{a_i}=1$ and $\sum{b_i}=1$, respectively, then the stationarity condition is
$$
f'\big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\big)+\lambda=0\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,K
$$
$$
f\big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\big)-\frac{a_i}{b_i}\cdot f'\big(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\big)+\pi=0\text{ for all }i=1,\dots,K
$$
If we plug in $a_i=b_i=1/K$, then, since $f(1)=f'(1)=0$, these two conditions are satisfied by $\lambda=\pi=0$. The points $a_i=b_i=1/K$ are clearly primal feasible, and thus the KKT conditions are satisfied for the proposed point, proving that it is indeed optimal.

---

**Edit** There's actually a simpler *ad hoc* argument here that doesn't use duality theory or the convexity of $f$ (though it's far less general). For your particular function $f$, we have that $f(t)\geq0$ for all $t\geq0$ (let's define $f(0)=\infty$ for simplicity). Hence, the objective function $\sum_ib_if(a_i/b_i)\geq0$ for all $a,b\geq0$ (*i.e.* this is a globally-valid lower bound). Since $f(1)=0$, this lower bound is attained when $a_i=b_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,K$. The equality constraints dictate that $a_i=1/K$ for all $i$, and thus $a_i=b_i=1/K$ for all $i=1,\dots,K$ is the global minimizer.

Comment: Thanks. I was more interested in the case where we take $f(0)=0$ with the use of indicator function. But, this was also helpful.

Comment: @kko I would recommend posting a new question with the specifics of what you want for the $a_i=0$ (_etc._) cases!

Comment: Thanks David. I re-posted the question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152370/multivariate-convex-optimization-problem-involving-logarithms-2.